# Group by without losing a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to get each states' election winner from a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/roydatascience/us-election-results-2020/data?select=president_county_candidate.csv) which has the votes for every county in the 2020 presidential elections.

I started off with this

```
    data = pd.read_csv('..\Data\president_county_candidate.csv', lineterminator='\n')
    
    group = data.groupby(
        ['state', 'candidate'], as_index=False
    ).agg(
            totalVoteSum=('total_votes', 'sum')
    )
    group
```

The result is currently this
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDeWC.png)

What I would like to have now is a list of states with the winning candidate, e.g.

| State | Candidate | Votes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alaska | Donald Trump | 1441168 |
| Alabama | Donald Trump | 189892 |

I tried this:

```
group = group.groupby(
    ['state'], as_index=False
).agg(
        winner=('totalVoteSum', 'max')
)
group
```

Which gives the correct result but skips the candidate column.

How do I get the column to remain without grouping by it which obviously gives a wrong result?

Answer (score 1):

This works, I'm not sure how though:

```
idx = group.groupby(['state'])['totalVoteSum'].transform(max) == group['totalVoteSum']

group[idx]
```

Thanks [RJ Andriaansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11380795/rj-adriaansen)